# Tunnel HTTP through HTTPS using Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, tomcat, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to have an HTTPS frontend for an HTTP server?

Let me elaborate. Say I have an app running on a tomcat instance and this app only understands HTTP. Is it possible to have Apache sit in front of the tomcat app and proxying the requests as shown below:

```
        http://example.com/proxied_app                     http://localhost:8080
                       +----------+                        +----------+
                       |          |                        |          |
                       |          |                        |          |
Internet <----HTTPS--->|  APACHE  |<---------HTTP--------->|  TOMCAT  |
                       |          |                        |          |
                       |          |                        |          |
                       +----------+                        +----------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. That's what [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) is for.

Comment: If you're connecting to a Tomcat instance, consider using [`mod_proxy_ajp`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html). Same configuration but uses a Tomcat connector for better performance.

Comment: If you choose to use HTTP between webserver and tomcat, consider replacing apache by varnish for real performance reason

Answer (score 1):

Jenny D answer is fine: just to add that in this case you can also use [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/) when connecting Apache Httpd with Apache Tomcat.

Comment: These days mod_ajp is a much better option.

Comment: @bahamat do you mean `mod_proxy_ajp`?

Comment: @TomMarthenal: Yes, that's the one. (I didn't look it up, just wrote that from memory and I haven't used it in a while). Thanks.